# How can I find the size of an initializer in C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to define a list which includes the MAC addresses of our devices. And I would like to do it with a macro. Here is a sample of the list I defined:

```
#define WHITELIST_DEVICE {                                  \
                      {0x45,0x11,0xDF,0xED,0x2B,0x61},  \
                      {0xAB,0x11,0xDF,0x61,0x6B,0x2B},  \
                      {0x61,0x6B,0x3B,0xED,0x61,0x61},  \
                      {0xDF,0x55,0xDF,0x6B,0x6B,0x61},  \
                     } /**< List of device mac addresses in whitelist*/
```

After defining the list, I would like to gather its size like columns and rows. What is the easiest way to do that?
You can also suggest me a new way to define the list. The code will work on an Embedded System. So, it shouldn't have heavy algorithms :)

Comment: why do you need columns? There will be always 6 right?

Comment: The code you have posted is not an array, it is an initializer. Post the code for the array definition.

Comment: Actually, you are right. I do not need columns.
I will edit the title as initializer, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming there are always six columns, you can do the calculation by using the above initializer in a compound literal.

```
#define WHITELIST_DEVICE_LENGTH ( sizeof ((int[][6])WHITELIST_DEVICE) / sizeof ((int[][6])WHITELIST_DEVICE[0]) )
```

or

```
#define WHITELIST_DEVICE_LENGTH ( sizeof ((int[][6])WHITELIST_DEVICE) / sizeof (int[6]) /* a "row" */ )
```

`(int[][6])WHITELIST_DEVICE` - Would normally creates an anonymous object in the scope it appears in. But when the literal is an operand to `sizeof` (expression variant) it will not create any object, instead only doing calculation on the types in question during compilation.

The `sizeof` trick for getting an array size needs no explaining I hope. It also makes the choice of `int` as array element immaterial, since that size will be canceled out during division. I chose that type to avoid any potential issues with your literal numbers not fitting in the array elements.

Comment: Interestingly, it works correctly if you use `char` or `unsigned char` instead of `int` for the base type of the array.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Due to the division, as I just edited in. Didn't want to stumble upon any pathological cases by using `char` (in case it's signed) and `unsigned char` is just too much noise for such a macro IMO. `int` works well.

Comment: To clarify this a bit, the parenthesis here `(int[][6])` belongs to the compound literal and not the `sizeof` operator. Compound literals counting as postfix operators with higher precedence than `sizeof`. And then `sizeof` can be used without a parenthesis around its operand if the operand is an expression and not a type, which is the case here.

Comment: So for the sake of readability I would probably recommend to do `#define WHITELIST_DEVICE_SIZE ( sizeof ((uin8_t[])WHITELIST_DEVICE) )` instead.

Comment: @Lundin - Sure. I also renamed it to avoid confusion with size in bytes. I'm hesitant about using a type that requires another header, even a standard one for this. I'll leave the choice of type to the OP.

Comment: It's an embedded system so the OP can be assumed to include stdint.h in every single translation unit.

Comment: You could make the macro slightly shorter by dividing by the size of the row type instead of the size of a row of a compound literal: `#define WHITELIST_DEVICE_LENGTH ( sizeof ((int[][6])WHITELIST_DEVICE) / sizeof (int[6]) )`

Comment: @IanAbbott - Indeed. I considered it, but wasn't sure which way would be more idiomatic. In retrospect perhaps it's best to show both

Comment: I don't know which way is more idiomatic either, since technically, the original way has two compound literals and is dividing the size of one by the size of a row of the other!

Comment: @IanAbbott - True. But the general form of the trick is `sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]`. Superficially at least, `arr` appears twice as a token sequence. And I hoped to be inline with that idiom.

Comment: But the two `arr`s are different objects in this case (in the ephemeral sense, since the objects only exist in the eyes of the compiler in this case).

Comment: @IanAbbott - As I agreed already. But to the eyes of the programmer, it at least *looks* (superficially) like the idiom they know already. It was an attempt to communicate what was being accomplished. But perhaps a poor attempt.